# google map api eliminate calling twice

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I'm just starting json and google maps api using [this video tutorial on youtube](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=OS2Nj5G9cGs&index=1&t=94s&list=WL) from 2013 as the example. I've got the demo map to display but it's giving me a

> You have included the Google Maps API multiple times on this page. This may cause unexpected errors.

The original code didn't have an api key call, which I added, but I guess that calls the api twice. How do I not call the api twice?

```
<head>
<script src="https://maps.google.com/maps/api/js?sensor=false"></script>

    <script>
      // The web service URL from Drive 'Deploy as web app' dialog.
      var DATA_SERVICE_URL = "https://script.google.com/macros/s/SPREADSHEET_ID/exec=?jsonp=callback";
      var map;
      function initialize() {
        map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map_canvas'), {
          center: new google.maps.LatLng(0, 0),
          zoom: 2,
          maxZoom: 20,
          mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
        });
        var scriptElement = document.createElement('script');
        scriptElement.src = DATA_SERVICE_URL;
        document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0].appendChild(scriptElement);
      }
      function callback(data) {
        for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
          var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
            position: new google.maps.LatLng(data[i][3], data[i][2]),
            map: map
          });
        }
      }
    </script>

    <script async defer src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=#######&callback=jsonp"></script>

  </head>
```

Comment: **Don't include the API twice..."**, combine any parameters needed into the original call.

Answer (score 0):

Oh, apparently the **sensor** parameter is no longer needed so I can just

```
<head>
  <script async defer src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=#######&callback=jsonp"></script>

    <script>
      // The web service URL from Drive 'Deploy as web app' dialog.
      var DATA_SERVICE_URL = "https://script.google.com/macros/s/SPREADSHEET_ID/exec=?jsonp=callback";
      var map;
      function initialize() {
        map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map_canvas'), {
          center: new google.maps.LatLng(0, 0),
          zoom: 2,
          maxZoom: 20,
          mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
        });
        var scriptElement = document.createElement('script');
        scriptElement.src = DATA_SERVICE_URL;
        document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0].appendChild(scriptElement);
      }
      function callback(data) {
        for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
          var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
            position: new google.maps.LatLng(data[i][3], data[i][2]),
            map: map
          });
        }
      }
    </script>
  </head>
```